# Static HttpClient Seems to sometimes cache redirect

Tags: asp.net, dotnet-httpclient

I have an asp.net (4.5.1) web app running on a 25 server webfarm.  The app is mostly webapi with a few webforms.  It's the backend for a single page application.

Our application makes a lot of outbound backend rest calls.  We use HttpClient for this.  About 6 months ago we discovered a performance issue using HttpClient with SSL endpoints (HTTPS).  Under high loads we were seeing lost connections.  It turned out that we were creating a new HttpClient within a using for each request.  This worked well for HTTP, but when we switched to make calls using HTTPS, we ran into performance issues.  To address this we made our HttpClient static so it would get reused.  We theorized that the latency and lost connections was caused by re-establishing the SSL connection with each call.  By making it static, we made use of some internal .Net functionality that maintained the SSL connection.

In the end, after this change, we halved our response times by doing this and everything seemed ok.  No more lost connections either.

....until the other day when we noticed an issue.

One of the services we call was having a maintenance downtime.  During the downtime, they redirected to a maintenance page.  Our HttpClient is following redirects, so we wound up generating an error since we were expecting json, not a maintenance html page.  This was expected though.

The problem was that after the maintenance was completed and the redirect was removed on the other service.  Two of our 25 servers continued to hit the redirected page instead of the page they were supposed to be hitting.

I can only assume that this was due to using the static HttpClient because when our app pool eventually recycled (scheduled each morning), the problem went away.

Does anyone have any thoughts or ideas about this?  Am I missing something?  Do you think this was caused by having a static HttpClient?  Can you think of any way to reduce the risk of this happening again?

Comment: Just curious, how are you managing the maintenance redirect? Sending HTTP 307 Temporary Redirect seems like a good fit for this scenario (and making sure your host doesn't allow caching of that response, which is usually the default handling for 307s). https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.8

Comment: I'm not sure.  The redirect configured by a service outside of mine.  HttpClient follows redirects by default so it just followed it.